# Is there any Java library that can read and write plist files, including binary format?

Tags: java, xml, plist

Is there any Java library that can read and write plist files, including in their binary format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration) ? They seem to provide what you're looking for using [`PropertyListConfiguration`](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/plist/PropertyListConfiguration.html) and other classes of the [`org.apache.commons.configuration.plist`](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/plist/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: That handles the text and XML formats, but not the binary format. The OP wants the binary format too, but this is certainly a very good start.

Answer (score 1):

[dd-plist](https://github.com/3breadt/dd-plist) can read and write Cocoa framework binary `.plist` files.

```
NSDictionary rootDict = (NSDictionary) PropertyListParser.parse(new File("my.plist"));
for (String name : rootDict.allKeys()) {
    NSObject value = rootDict.objectForKey(name);
    System.out.println(name + " = " + value);
}
```

It can also convert a plist to XML and back. e.g.:

```
PropertyListParser.convertToXml(new File("my.plist"), new File("my.xml"));
```

`PropertyListParser.parse` can then read back `.plist` as well as `.xml` format.

---

Note: there's also [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration2/plist/PropertyListConfiguration.html), but it can only read/write old-style (ASCII) plist files, which are never used on iOS or macOS nowadays.